# CSS display:table and padding-top

Tags: html, css, padding, css-tables

I am currently using `display:table` in CSS in order to place some blocks in a form.

But there is a behaviour I cannot understand: when two blocks are set with `display:table-cell;`, both depending on a `display:table` father div, it is impossible to put a margin or a padding-top on only one block, without applying it on the second.

A quick example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nW8Dg/2/)

I only want to put a `padding-top` on the second block.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add vertical-align:top to the one that you want place up, and to the other one add the padding that you need to go down.

```
.col1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nW8Dg/5/

Answer (score 1):

Not with table appearance for sure, use list instead or inline-blocks